# Input dispatching timed out with HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I get lot of ANR reports (google play console) for which I have no clue how to solve it. I wrapped the problematic code with try and catch, but still it hangs at a specific codeline. I myself can't reproduce, but I ANR reports in the console.

Does anyone that understands the exception below in combination with the code and knows how to handle it?

```
private static boolean urlExists(String urlString) {
    HttpURLConnection huc;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode(); <-------------- line 246. Here is the problem.
        return responseCode != 404;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

ANR Report looks like this:

```
Thread

"main" tid=1 Native

  #00  pc 0x000000000009b114  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (recvfrom+16)
  #01  pc 0x000000000001aceb  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdk.so (NET_Read+36)
  #02  pc 0x000000000001b3d5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libopenjdk.so (SocketInputStream_socketRead0+176)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 (Native method)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead (SocketInputStream.java:118)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:173)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read (SocketInputStream.java:143)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read (Okio.java:138)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read (AsyncTimeout.java:213)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf (RealBufferedSource.java:307)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf (RealBufferedSource.java:301)
  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict (RealBufferedSource.java:197)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse (Http1xStream.java:188)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders (Http1xStream.java:129)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse (HttpEngine.java:750)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse (HttpEngine.java:622)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
  at mycompany.mypackage.images.ImageFetcher.urlExists (ImageFetcher.java:246)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you right. What does crash? You app? At the line 246? ANR (whatever it is)? Your app crashes with that  stacktrace? Does it crash each time it reaches the line 246 or eventually?

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I just read your stack trace more thoroughly. It looks scary.  Bad luck